# Is there a better way to write this recursing method in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, recursion, promise

I'm trying to write a method to find all the files in a folder, including subfolders. It's pretty simple to write using `fs.readdirSync`, but I'm trying to write a version which doesn't block. (i.e. uses `fs.readdir`).

I've got a version which works, but it's not pretty. Can someone who has a bit more experience with node see if there is a nicer way to write this? I can see a few other places in my codebase where I can apply this pattern so it would be nice to have a cleaner version!

```js
  private static findFilesFromFolder(folder: string): Promise<string[]> {
    let lstat = util.promisify(fs.lstat)
    let readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)

    // Read the initial folder
    let files = readdir(folder)

      // Join the folder name to the file name to make it absolute
      .then(files => files.map(file => path.join(folder, file)))

      // Get the stats for each file (also as a promise)
      .then(files =>
        Promise.all(files.map(file =>
          lstat(file).then(stats => { return { file: file, stats: stats } })
        ))
      )

      // If the file is a folder, recurse. Otherwise just return the file itself.
      .then(info =>
        Promise.all(info.map(info => {
          if (info.stats.isDirectory()) {
            return this.findFilesFromFolder(info.file)
          } else {
            return Promise.resolve([info.file])
          }
        }
      )))

      // Do sume munging of the types - convert Promise<string[][]> to Promise<string[]>
    .then(nested => Array.prototype.concat.apply([], nested) as string[])

    return files
  }
```

Comment: Don't make it an `async` function when you don't use `await` anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi removed.

Comment: Using await, will make the reursive code be pretty close to the sync verison

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You should add that as an answer - I'd totally forgotten while I was writing this that using await doesn't block but uses promises under the hood. You're right, it's much much cleaner now!

Comment: @deanWombourne I was working on the answer, but converting takes a bit of time  and I see Bergi beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do a few things to make this cleaner:

- move the recursion base case from within the loop to the top level
- use `async`/`await` syntax
- use `const` instead of `let`

Also put the `promisify` calls to where you are `import`ing `fs`

```
const lstat = util.promisify(fs.lstat)
const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)

…
private static async findFilesFromPath(folder: string): Promise<string[]> {
  const stats = await lstat(folder);
  // If the file is a folder, recurse. Otherwise just return the file itself.
  if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    // Read the initial folder
    const files = await readdir(folder);
    // Join the folder name to the file name to make it absolute
    const paths = files.map(file => path.join(folder, file))
    const nested = await Promise.all(paths.map(p => this.findFilesFromPath(p)))
    // Do sume munging of the types - convert string[][] string[]
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], nested) as string[];
  } else {
    return [folder];
  }
}
```

Comment: Using await was the critical thing I'd missed - I'd (embarrassingly) forgotten that await doesn't block, it's just Promises really. Though, why would you put the promisify as a global var instead of just in this method (I don't use them anywhere else, otherwise the answer is obvious!)?

Comment: @deanWombourne So that `promisify` is called only once, not through every method call.

Comment: Oh, of course, it's recursing! What a schoolboy error, I'm not having a great day!

Comment: Not just due to the recursion, but also when you call your method from outside multiple times. Admittedly, `promisify` does cache its result so it won't be a performance problem when you put it inside, but I still consider it cleaner - and also it enables reuse elsewhere in the module, even if you don't have the need *yet*.

Comment: Hah, we differ there - I wouldn't move them out until I needed to (though, due to recursion, I _did_ need to, oops). Interesting that promisify caches - I didn't know that.